# where i must put my javascript functions for better performance, in app/views/layout/users_layout.ctp or in app/views/users/index.ctp file?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

i am new cakephp ,so i want to know that where i could put javascript function in m cakephp?
i am new cakephp ,so i want to know that where i could put javascript function in m cakephp?
i am new cakephp ,so i want to know that where i could put javascript function in m cakephp?
i am new cakephp ,so i want to know that where i could put javascript function in m cakephp?
i am new cakephp ,so i want to know that where i could put javascript function in m cakephp?
i am new cakephp ,so i want to know that where i could put javascript function in m cakephp?
i am new cakephp ,so i want to know that where i could put javascript function in m cakephp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your JS in an external file, like /app/webroot/js/yourjs.js then use the following in your layout;

```
<html>

  <head>
  <?php echo $this->Html->script('yourjs'); ?>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>

</html>
```

Put your JS in an external file, like /app/webroot/js/yourjs.js then use the following in your layout;

```
<html>

  <head>
  <?php echo $this->Html->script('yourjs'); ?>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>

</html>
```

Put your JS in an external file, like /app/webroot/js/yourjs.js then use the following in your layout;

```
<html>

  <head>
  <?php echo $this->Html->script('yourjs'); ?>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>

</html>
```

etc..